# Adding AutoComplete in JComboBox without using extended Libraries

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

Is there any way to add the Auto-Complete and Instant Search like features in `JComboBox` (Java Swings) without using extended libraries (e.g. SwingX)?

Comment: Yes, it's a complete pain in the backside. You need a custom editor, which you monitor the document for changes. You need to filter the list model as the user types, but you'll need to hide and reshow the combo box popup as it does not resize itself in response to model changes...or at least it didn't when I last tried

Comment: SwingX is freeware so you can take the code from the autocomplete combo box without to use the complete lib.